# Change Twig Template variable with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony, twig

I'am trying to reload a part of my html with a new value that I've got using AJAX.

There is a

```
{% for client in clients %}
```

loop, and i've got a new set of clients using AJAX :

```
        $search = $request->request->get('data');

        $clients=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(
        Client::class)->findBy(array('name'=>$search));

        $response = new JsonResponse();
        $response->setStatusCode(200);
        return $response->setData(['search' => $clients ]);
```

I'm trying to change clients with the newly retrieved data.

Is there a way to do it ? Or should I try another technique ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could not do that because twig is rendered at the server side.
you will need to update the HTML generated by `{% for client in clients%}`
using javascript

Answer (score 3):

You can't change the value of the `clients` via AJAX because this template has already been rendered. You could however create a separate twig template like this:

```
{# loop.html.twig #}
{% for client in clients %}
.. your code
{% endfor %}
```

Then include it in your template like this:

```
<div id="client-loop-container">
    {% include 'loop.html.twig' %}
</div>
```

So in your ajax controller:

```
$clients=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(
        Client::class)->findBy(array('name'=>$search));

$template = $this->render('yourTemplate.html.twig')->getContent();
$response = new JsonResponse();
$response->setStatusCode(200);
return $response->setData(['template' => $template ]);
```

Finally in your ajax you should have something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    success: function(response) {
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        $("div#client-loop-container").html(response.template);    
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

in your controller

```
$clients=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(
        Client::class)->findBy(array('name'=>$search));

return $this->render('yourTemplate.html.twig')->getContent();
```

in your twig

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {

        $("div#client-loop-container").html(data);    
    }
});
```